# Regular expression pattern to match string without any 2 consecutive repeated characters

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I can very easily write a regular expression to match a string that contains 2 consecutive repeated characters:

```
/(\w)\1/
```

How do I do the complement of that? I want to match strings that don't have 2 consecutive repeated characters. I've tried variations of the following without success:

```
/(\w)[^\1]/ ;doesn't work as hoped
/(?!(\w)\1)/ ;looks ahead, but some portion of the string will match
/(\w)(?!\1)/ ;again, some portion of the string will match
```

I don't want any language/platform specific way to take the negation of a regular expression. I want the straightforward way to do this.

Comment: try `^(?!.*(\w)\1).*`

Comment: post some examples along with expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj - that worked! I'm not exactly sure why it worked... I guess I need to read up on lookaheads as I clearly don't fully understand them. Write your response as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below regex would match the strings which don't have any repeated characters.

```
^(?!.*(\w)\1).*
```

`(?!.*(\w)\1)` negative lookahead which asserts that the string going to be matched won't contain any repeated characters. `.*(\w)\1` will match the string which has repeated characters at the middle or at the start or at the end. `^(?!.*(\w)\1)` matches all the starting boundaries except the one which has repeated characters. And the following `.*` matches all the characters exists on that particular line. Note this this matches empty strings also. If you don't want to match empty lines then change `.*` at the last to `.+`

Note that `^(?!(\w)\1)` checks for the repeated characters only at the start of a string or line.

Lookahead and lookbehind, collectively called ["lookaround"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), are zero-length assertions just like the start and end of line. They do not consume characters in the string, but only assert whether a match is possible or not. Lookaround allows you to create regular expressions that are impossible to create without them, or that would get very longwinded without them.